# Regression-multiple observations per subject

Tags: regression

I have data for about 1 year, 100 observations, multiple observations per subject, transactions occur on weekly basis but have 6-12 subjects per week, there is no order to this. There is a policy change in latter half of year, I want to model change in dependent variable due to policy change as a dummy variable: time1=0, time2=1.

- Is this a case for fixed effects estimation?

The number of weeks per subject varies a lot and the number of weeks in time1 is greater than time2.  Computed means for time1, time2 and percent change=large change in dependent variable, estimated linear model:
pay=X1 X2 Time(dummy). Dummy variable is not statistically significant.

- Any suggestions as to how to model this? 
  Can I treat it as panel data?

Answer (score 1):

If you estimate the policy change as a fixed effects estimation in the context of an OLS regression you'll over-estimate your degrees of freedom because of the repeated measures by subject.  If you do not think there is an overall trend of time (beyond the policy shift) then there is no reason to keep all of the observations, you could simply aggregate by subject for "before policy change" and "after policy change" and do a paired samples t-test.  Failing that - if you intend to add more predictors, like perhaps a linear effect of time, you might think about liner mixed effects regression, e.g.

```
lmer(pay ~ time * policy + (1+time|SubjID))
```

... might be a good place to start.